# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined in an attempt to autoscroll to gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am new here and have tried to read through as many of the similarly titled topics as I can and have tried the solutions and none have worked for me...

I have a one page navigation, the idea is that the site should scroll to the relevant section (via hashtag) it seems that the sub menu is throwing up an error...

I'm using bootstrap framework

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#film-making">Filmmaking</a></li>
<!-- begin dropdown -->
<li class="dropdown">
    <a id="showcase_menulink" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#showcase">Photography</a>
    <!-- submenu -->
    <ul id="showcase_menu" class="dropdown-menu navmenu-nav">
        <li><a href="#brides">Brides</a></li>
        <li><a href="#couples">Happy Couples</a></li>
        <li><a href="#hands">Hands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#venues">Venues</a></li>
        <li><a href="#forgotten">Forgotten Things</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /submenu -->
    </li>
<li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="#packages">Packages</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see from the code it's the standard Bootstrap layout, including the dropdown-menu .
The script I'm using to animate the page is as follows

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var target = this.hash,
         $target = $(target);
         $('html, body').stop().animate({
             'scrollTop': $target.offset().top ***line9***
         }, 900, 'swing', function () {
         window.location.hash = target;
         });
     });
});
```

I keep getting an error which is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined... line 9
```

which is the asterisks above... "

I've tried numerous fixes from other similar questions but didn't find a solution.

Comment: If `this.hash` is a selector that doesn't return an element `$(target)` will be an empty jQuery object that has no offset, so `offset()` will return `undefined`, and `undefined` has no `top` property.

Comment: Agree with adeneo. Do you have elements on the page with ids of 'brides', 'couples', etc.

Comment: If you look at the following jsfiddle you'll notice I added three divs to the 'page' with the correct ids. When you click on brides, couples, and hands you don't get the error. When you click on the others you still will. http://jsfiddle.net/435BT/

Comment: No the #ID's in the submenu were for the purpose of sorting like what you get with Quicksand.js but I hadn't got that far yet...

Comment: @ChrisB Thanks very much I fully understand where I went wrong now to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your page includes dom elements with id's equal to the hash values of your href locations. For example if you have a link like the following:

```
<li><a href="#brides">Brides</a></li>
```

you need a corresponding element (doesn't have to be a div) like this:

```
<div id="brides"></div>
```

Here is an example fiddle with divs for brides, couples, and hands just as an example.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/435BT/1/)